# How to activate two network interfaces at a time?

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat

I have two network interfaces. Both interfaces have two private ip each for a total of 4. All are set to elastic ip.

I can ping only two public IP.

How can I activate 4 IP at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the secondory IPs from ec2 OS too.

From AWS Documentation:

Configuring the Operating System on Your Instance to Recognize the Secondary Private IPv4 Address

> After you assign a secondary private IPv4 address to your instance,
>   you need to configure the operating system on your instance to
>   recognize the secondary private IP address.
>
> If you are using Amazon Linux, the ec2-net-utils package can take care
>   of this step for you. It configures additional network interfaces that
>   you attach while the instance is running, refreshes secondary IPv4
>   addresses during DHCP lease renewal, and updates the related routing
>   rules. You can immediately refresh the list of interfaces by using the
>   command sudo service network restart and then view the up-to-date list
>   using ip addr li. If you require manual control over your network
>   configuration, you can remove the ec2-net-utils package. For more
>   information, see Configuring Your Network Interface Using
>   ec2-net-utils. If you are using another Linux distribution, see the
>   documentation for your Linux distribution. Search for information
>   about configuring additional network interfaces and secondary IPv4
>   addresses. If the instance has two or more interfaces on the same
>   subnet, search for information about using routing rules to work
>   around asymmetric routing. For information about configuring a Windows
>   instance, see [Configuring a Secondary Private IP Address for Your
>   Windows Instance in a VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/config-windows-multiple-ip.html) in the Amazon EC2 User Guide for Windows
>   Instances

For Linux here is the post where the steps are explained:
https://bobcares.com/blog/an-easy-guide-to-setup-amazon-ec2-multiple-ips/